# Issues Migrating extjs 4.0.7 to 4.1.1

Tags: grid, extjs4, scrollbar, extjs4.1, treepanel

I'm having a few issues when attempting to make the switch from extjs 4.0.7 to 4.1.1.

The first issue is as follow:

I have two treepanels which are within a column layout. One right next to the other. My app loads a bunch of nodes into the left panel, and then you can optionally move some of them to the other panel. However, the panel with all the nodes is not showing a scrollbar, and thus I can't see about 1/3 of the nodes all of a sudden. I had a semi-similar issue in 4.0.7 where I couldnt see the last node moved if the panel was full until I moved another node. I fixed that with the following lines:

```
treePanel1.invalidateScroller();
treePanel2.invalidateScroller();
```

These lines are deprecated in 4.1.1, and the problem seems to have become worse. Has anyone had a similar issue, and how do I get my scroll bar back.

A second major issue related to my UI:

I have two grids right next to each other elsewhere, layed out similarly to the treepanels. I've set up drag and drop between the two grids. Again all the nodes start in the left grid, with the option to drag some into the right grid. However, the right grid is now not showing at full size, it is defaulting to a sliver. So, the DD functionality is still there, if you know to drag the node to that little sliver. Afterwards, the sliver expands enough to hold the single node and so on. So, how do I get it back to defaulting full size. Why had extjs 4.1.1 caused these issues? I'd have to fat finger in any code, but can if absolutely neccessary. However, if anyone is familiar with this type of issue based on my description, that would be great.

**Edit:** Also, I have a combobox in the right-most column of the grids. When I click to change one of the comboboxes, a mini scrollbar thing pops up that sort of blocks the dropdown button. What have they done to this version?

Here is the layout definition where I have the first problem where the scrollbar doesn't show up on the panel when it needs to:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Select fields',
    defaults: {
        border: false,
        height: '100%'
    },
    layout: 'column',
    items: [

        {
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        itemID: 'choicesTreePanel',
        title: 'Choose from below fields',
        height: '100%',
        multiSelect: true,
        store: choicesTree,
        rootVisible: false,
        columnWidth: .44},

    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        columnWidth: .06,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center'
        },
        defaults: {
            margins: "15 0 0 0"
        },
        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: '==>'},
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: '<=='},
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'RST'}

             ]},
    {
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        itemId: 'chosenTreePanel',
        title: 'Fields',
        border: true,
        store: chosenFields,
        rootVisible: false,
        columnWidth: .44,
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop,
        dragText:'
                dragginggggg '
        },
        ddGroup: '
                fieldsDD '        
        }
        },
        {xtype:'
                panel ',
        columnWidth:.06,
        layout:{
        type:'
                vbox ',
        align:'
                center '
        },
        items: [
            {
            xtype: '
                button ',
            text: '
                UP '},
        {
            xtype: '
                button ',
            text: '
                DOWN '}

             ]
        }

        ]
 }
```

Edit: on the left panel, if I make height a set value, and autoscroll true, I have a scrollbar. If I set height '100%' and autoscroll true, there is no scroll bar. So a solution might be to find out how to have the panel fit the height of the parent, while maintaining the scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are looking for a percentage based height solution, you can also use a constant value height. In many cases this will avoid your problem. For example, set the panels to 600 height, that should fix the scroller issue.

This does not solve your issue in percentage based layouts. Hopefully someone else can provide help with that.

Answer (score 1):

(maybe it is best to split your question into multiple separate questions)

Concerning your first question about the panel height and scrollbar:

In your example I would ask myself the question "I want the treepanel to have a 100% height related to what?".

A column layout is typically used when you don't care about the height of the child elements related to their parent: the sum of the height of the child elements define the height of the column as you can see here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples/layout/column.html.

You did not define any height on the columns, so it uses the height of the child elements (which have no height in your example). I don't know what Ext does in this case, but based on this, it cannot do anything smart.

If you want the treepanel to use the whole height of the containing panel, you would use a **hbox** layout with the align property set to **stretch**.
That might fix the scrollbar too since height calculation can be done properly.
Don't forget to remove the "height: 100%" and "autoscroll" properties since they mix things up.

Finally, changing the layout of the treepanel to 'fit' might give you the result you are looking for.

Your code might become something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        layout: 'fit',
        flex: 44,
        ...
    }, {
        flex: 6,
        ...
    },{
        flex: 44,
        ...
    }]
}
```

I did not test this answer on your code. Please provide a full working code sample (with a dummy store) and I'll test it.

Comment: Added note: I don't think your issues are that much related to bugs in 4.1 but rather due to better layout rendering in this version.